# However in the middle of a sentence

Tags: word-order, syntactic-analysis

I wonder if I can use however like in this sentence:

> The lecture however does cover a lot of information, still doesn't
>   explain the main subject.

Sounds a bit awkward to me, but it still seems that I've met something like this somewhere. What do you think?

Comment: Your example sentence is mainly ungrammatical because of what comes after the comma. But it would probably be improved by putting ***however*** after the word it's most likely to be modifying (in this case, probably ***does***, not ***lecture***).

Comment: When it's used parenthetically (as in your specimen sentence), it improves comprehensibility to mark off *however* with a comma on either side: "The lecture, however, does cover ..." On another matter: there seems to be a 'but' missing: "... **but** still doesn't explain the main subject".

Comment: @Erik: I don't know about you, but with no other context I'd be inclined to assume ***however*** modifies ***lecture*** with the word order as given. Which forces me to assume some slightly contrived context where the *lecture* is being given "faint praise" because at least it gives broad coverage (in contrast to something else previously mentioned, such as the preprinted notes, which didn't even manage to do *that*).

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify it right away. "However" was intended to modify the verb, and was not related to any context.

Comment: I think you want "although it" instead of "however".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I agree that your interpretation is the most plausible; all things being equal, I would word it the way you did. But as you imply, without additional context it's not possible to be completely sure what the questioner intended to focus on, so I preferred to discuss those other aspects of the question.

Comment: @TRomano - Better still: **"Although** the lecture **covers** [or **contains**, as Ron Kyle suggests below] a lot of information, **it** still doesn't explain the main subject".

Comment: It's grammatical and makes sense. 1. *However* **can** be placed in the middle of a sentence. 2. It can appear/move anywhere depending on the author's intent of laying focus of meaning. 3. In this case, it correctly emphasize **does** (the word *does* would not have been necessary if it were not the focus.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The lecture however does cover a lot of information, still doesn't explain the main subject."

You could say "The lecture, however, does cover a lot of information while still not explaining the main subject." if you're stuck on where however goes.

You could say "However, the lecture DOES cover a lot of information while still not explaining the main subject." or "The lecture DOES cover a lot of information; however it still doesn't explain the main subject" if you're stuck on using however and don't mind a semi-colon

I would probably say "While the lecture does contain a lot of information, it still doesn't explain the main subject."
Hope this helps

Comment: Those commas are not mandatory though. It works even without them.

Comment: Which commas? There's s lot of them... you mean the first "...lecture, however,...", right? (Wow, that sentence was comma crazy; did I do it right? I have doubts inside the quotes. :) )